# Is "absenteeism" really a common used noun in business?

Tags: word-choice

During study business exam level 2, I came across the word "absenteeism" describing an absence from work or office.  Another phrase was "rate of absenteeism" and "sickness absence". Are these really common used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is commonly used with reference to the workplace:

***[Absenteeism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absenteeism):***

> - chronic absence (as from work or school); also : the rate of such absence

(M-W)

See also [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absenteeism%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsenteeism%3B%2Cc0)

BusinessDictionary.com provides a more detailed definition,  [Absenteeism](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/absenteeism.html) :

> Voluntary non attendance at work, without valid reason. Absenteeism means either habitual evasion of work, or willful absence as in a strike action. It does not include involuntary or occasional absence due to valid causes, or reasons beyond one's control, such as accidents or sickness.

Comment: So, if someone is sick including a sick report (valid reason) and not able to work, it is no absenteeism ?

Comment: @FrankMK- no, in that case  it is not.